# Expand $[\frac{\tau^2}{16}(\frac{v}{i+1}+1)^2+\frac{1}{2}]^{-a-2}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How to expand the expression as showed in the title about $v=0$, in which, $a$ is a natural number and $\tau$ is a real number and $i$ is the complex unit. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\left[\frac{\tau^2}{16}\left(\frac{v}{i+1}+1\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\right]^{-a-2}$$

First factor the quadratic polynomial inside the power $$\left[\frac{\tau^2}{16}\left(\frac{v}{i+1}+1\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\right]^{-a-2}=\left[\frac{\tau}{4}\frac{v}{i+1}+\left(\frac{\tau}{4}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]^{-a-2}\left[\frac{\tau}{4}\frac{v}{i+1}+\left(\frac{\tau}{4}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]^{-a-2}.$$ 
Now use the binomial theorem with each factor:

$$\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-a-2}{k}\left(\frac{\tau}{4}\frac{v}{i+1}\right)^k\left(\frac{\tau}{4}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{-a-2-k}\right]\times\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-a-2}{k}\left(\frac{\tau}{4}\frac{v}{i+1}\right)^k\left(\frac{\tau}{4}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{-a-2-k}\right]$$

Finally, [multiply the two series above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division).

Comment: How can I get the first equation?

Comment: @Peng You can use that $a^2+b^2=(a+ib)(a-ib)$.

Comment: Is that true for all $v$ or only for the numbers in the vicinity of $v=0$?

Comment: Or is this Taylor expansion on $v=0$?

Comment: @Peng The [series coming from the binomial expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Convergence) have a finite interval of convergence, unless $-a-2$ is a natural (\geq0) number.

Comment: Shall I expand it as $[\frac{\tau^2}{4^2}(\frac{v}{i+1}+1)^2+\frac{1}{2}]^{-a-2}
=
\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}
\binom{-a-2}{b}
\frac{\tau^{2b}}{4^{2b}}(\frac{v}{i+1}+1)^{2b}
(\frac{1}{2})^{-a-2-b}
=
\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}
\binom{-a-2}{b}
\frac{\tau^{2b}}{4^{2b}}
\sum_{m=0}^{2b} (\frac{v}{i+1})^m
(\frac{1}{2})^{-a-2-b}$